# How to check for each of the items in a list if they are contained in a propery of a class via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity `Card` with a property `Title`. I also have a field for searching through all the cards' titles with a search term. Let's say that I have card titles 'Dark Magician' and 'Blue Eyed Dragon'. If I search for 'Magician Dragon' I need to receive both the cards, if I search for 'Blue dog with a house' I need to receive the 'Blue Eyed Dragon'card.
As of now I have this code, but I can't make up the correct LINQ code.

CardsController.cs, the All view:

```
public IActionResult All(string searchTerm)
        {
            var cardsQuery = this.data.Cards.AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
            {
                //Removing all the white spaces and then joining the different words by a space
                searchTerm = string.Join(" ", searchTerm.Split(default(string[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                //Splitting the searchTerm and making it a list of strings
                var searchTermSplitted = searchTerm.Split().ToList();

                //Trying to check if any and which words are contained in any of the cards' titles
                cardsQuery = cardsQuery
                    .Where(c => c.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchTermSplitted)); //Not working, just for the idea
            }

            var cards = cardsQuery
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
                .Select(c => new CardListingViewModel
                {
                    Title = c.Title,
                    ImageUrl = c.ImageUrl,
                    Category = c.Category.Name,
                    Condition = c.Condition.Name

                })
                .ToList();

            return View(new AllCardsQueryModel
            {
                Cards = cards
            }); ;
        }
```

Comment: Why `.AsQueryable()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
           List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

            string searchPattern = "Magician Dragon";
            List<string> searchWords = searchPattern.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

            var results = cards.AsEnumerable().Where(x => searchWords.Any(y => x.Title.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: When I tried that it gave me `InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Card>() .Where(c => __searchWords_0 .Any(y => c.Title.Contains(y)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.`

Comment: I made two changes.  Not sure if one or both are needed.

Comment: Why `.AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @Enigmativity : That is what the error message said.